# Does Bookshelf library support mongodb with node js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Does Bookshelf library support mongodb with node js?

If not, what can we use in place of it, which supports mongodb.  Currently, I am using mongoose.

Comment: Mongoose is a good choice. Bookshelf is an ORM for SQL databases, MongoDB is not an SQL database.

Comment: Hmm, thank you for your response